# Pixel Perfect UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uilabel

Here are two labels stacked directly on top of each other, with their backgrounds colored:

[image]

I always design my apps in Photoshop first. That dead space on the top and bottom of the labels makes it extremely difficult to position text precisely as in the design. How can I compensate for that top and bottom space when I want to place the label by top or bottom of the text?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding the question, what do you mean exactly by the dead space on the top and bottom of the labels?

Comment: @J2K The vertical space between the letters and the edges of the label.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `-sizeToFit` on the label in order to resize it.

> Call this method when you want to resize the current view so that it
>   uses the most appropriate amount of space. Specific UIKit views resize
>   themselves according to their own internal needs. In some cases, if a
>   view does not have a superview, it may size itself to the screen
>   bounds. Thus, if you want a given view to size itself to its parent
>   view, you should add it to the parent view before calling this method.

Comment: No dice. It's not a frame issue - it's because of the difference between cap height and ascender, as well as the descender. See here: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/02/understanding-uifont/

Answer (score 0):

Either use AutoLayout to size your labels exactly at the content size, or use `sizeToFit` in code and position your labels accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not create a background UIView with the background colour, and then add the label as a subview of the background view?